# SnakeYaml create object via static method

Tags: playframework-2.0, snakeyaml

I'm trying to use snakeyaml with Play Framework 2 to create Ebean objects

it works well with

```
!!models.User
  name: Leon
```

But I'd like to reference allready persisted items. which means I don't want to create new objects.

So if I do something like this to try to reference the already created group

```
!!models.Group &mygroup
  id: 1

!!models.User
  group: *mygroup
```

It will complain that the group with id: 1 already exists

Ebean has a a method `EbeanServer.getReference(type, id)` which is accessible from the static find method on the model class

```
Group.find.ref(1)
```

I would like to be able to do something like this (but it doesn't work now)

```
!!models.Group.find.ref(1) &mygroup
```

How can I call this static method from snakeyaml to get a reference instead of a new object?

Comment: Have you looked into custom constructors? I have an (old) example here:
https://github.com/mariussoutier/EOFFixtures/blob/master/Sources/de/soutier/fixtures/yaml/TimestampConstructor.scala

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I had to create a custom Yaml constructor that uses `Ebean.getServer("default").getReference(models.User.class, 1)`

https://gist.github.com/4326933

Hope it will help someone!